# Assign task to 300+ users

Tags: sharepoint-server, tasks

I have a need to assign tasks where 300+ individual users have to acknowledge that the content of a SharePoint list has not changed and that they've read the list.

- Each user must complete this on their own task
- Reminders have to be sent out reminding the user to do their part

In the past, I ran into timeout problems trying to assign 300+ tasks at once.

What approach do you take when assigning out mass policy acknowledgment tasks to all employees?

Comment: Dear Timothy, should you mention the SharePoint version at Quest tags , it will be useful for all

Comment: Also, which approach you have tried in the past and encountered timeout?

Answer (score 0):

For those that come across this in the future, I ended up going with a commercial solution called [DocRead](https://www.collaboris.com/products/docread/), developed by Collaboris.

They handle the task assignment outside of SharePoint, in a bespoke task management suite they bolt on to SharePoint that scales much better.