# Assigning tasks to 100+ users in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, tasks

We've got an Office 365 project that should help us manage a couple of hundred retail stores from a central office. The idea is to send a task to a group of stores (one task per store) or to all of them. Every store should receive a separate task and their management should complete it.

[image]

Would it be a good idea to assign a task to 100+ users by using a Designer/Nintex Online Workflows? I am concerned about the sheer number of tasks each workflow can generate. In theory, it should just work fine, but I am not sure if it's an enterprise-ready and a safe solution. Can someone share their experience and the ideas of the implementation? How did it work out in the end?

Sorry for a slightly open-ended question.

There was [a similar question concerning SharePoint Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191414/assign-task-to-300-users), but it still has 0 answers.

Comment: why not 100 tasks -- one per user?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean

Comment: In order to ensure that you don't assign tasks to inaktive/disabled users, I assume that you assign the tasks to an account that represents the store rather than the store manager?

Comment: That is a possibility, but we haven't thought about it. We have 3 people per store that should have enough permissions to "complete" the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no other answers I will leave my opinion here:

Creating 100 tasks in Nintex or SharePoint Designer workflows might not be the best option. Instead, I highly recommend using Microsoft Flow with the OOB Approval action. In fact, I can assign 100 approval tasks within a **single** MS Flow. That works extremely well. There are even Approve/Decline buttons that are rendered right in Outlook email.